# Get SVN revision number of Folder in Repository

Tags: macos, bash, shell, svn, command-line

Here is what I have in a BASH file running on mac

```
result=$(svn info $svn | awk '/Revision:/ { print $2 }')
```

This is great and works well except is it outputting the whole repositories folder.

For example:
Complete SVN path:
https://hello.com/this/svn/project/is/cool/  Revision is 31469

Directory I want the revision for
https://hello.com/this/svn/project/is/cool/and/so/is/this/  Revision is 31405

Opening a svn client will show the latest revision of the folder, but I need to automate this process. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Is `svnversion` installed alongside the `svn` binary? (`svnversion ./so/is/this`). If so, could you use that? Sorry, not terribly familiar with osx svn package contents...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Instead of `/Revision:/`, use:

```
result=$(svn info $svn | awk '/^Last Changed Rev:/ { print $4 }')
```